# How can I verify SHA-2 signature of PE file?

Tags: winapi, signature, sha2, winverifytrust

I would like to verify SHA-2 authenticode digital signature of PE file on Windows platform.

I tried to verify a SHA-2 signature by using `WinVerifyTrustEx()`.
`WinVerifyTrustEx` works fine on Windows 7. But `WinVerifyTrustEx` does not work on Windows Vista.

I used same codes on both Windows 7 and Windows Vista.

How can I verify SHA-2 signature on Window Vista?

[**UPDATE**]

`WinVerifyTrustEx` returns `TRUST_E_NOSIGNATURE(0x800B0100)` on Windows Vista.

`WinVerifyTrustEx` returns `ERROR_SUCCESS` on Windows 7.

I used same sample codes and verified the same executable file which is signed.
The signed executable file has SHA-256 signature.

The difference is only OS (vista and 7).

When I tried to verify another executable file which is signed by SHA-1, `WinVerifyTrustEx` returns `ERROR_SUCCESS` on both Vista and 7.

Comment: "does not work" how?

Comment: Perhaps there's a defect in your code. Which we cannot see.

Comment: Most likely Vista doesn't support SHA2, hence the problem. External library is needed in this case.

Comment: Could you teach me which external library can be used in this case?

Comment: Our SecureBlackbox supports SHA2 signatures in Authenticode.